# Java failed to compile Functional Interface with generic parameter and default method implementation

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I'm trying to extend this interface:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface HandlerFunction<T extends ServerResponse> {
    Mono<T> handle(ServerRequest request);
}
```

Like this:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface HandlerFn<R extends ServerRequest> extends HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> {
    default Mono<ServerResponse> handle(ServerRequest request) {
        return handleFn(request);
    }

    Mono<ServerResponse> handleFn(R request);
}
```

I'm getting this error (on `handleFn(request)`):

```
The method handleFn(R) in the type HandlerFn<R> is not applicable for the arguments (ServerRequest)
```

In this code snippet, why when calling `handleFn(request)` the type `R` is not inferred as `ServerRequest` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` is a `ServerRequest`, not an `R`. `R` *could* be `ServerRequest`, but it could be any other subclass of it.

`R` is declared on the class, not the method. The type of `R` is determined at the declaration of the reference to the `HandlerFn`, not at the call site of the `handleFn` method.

You could cast inside the default method:

```
return handleFn((R) request);
```

which is an unchecked cast (at that point; it would be checked elsewhere).

If you declared the method as a generic method, it would work in `handle`:

```
<RR extends ServerRequest> Mono<ServerResponse> handleFn(RR request);
```

(You wouldn't then need `R` on the interface. I just called it `RR` to emphasize that it is a separate type variable).

But, in fact, there is no point in such a type variable: this gives no advantage over declaring the method non-generically:

```
Mono<ServerResponse> handleFn(ServerRequest request);
```

which, of course, has no advantage over the `handle` method.